# Why does compare function of sort() work like that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've read in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) about compare function's work. This callback function can have 2 parameters. There are 3 "if" for them:

> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a value > than 0, sort b before a.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns a value < than 0, sort a before b.
> - If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns 0, a and b are considered equal.

So, as far as I see, if compare function returns a value less than zero, compare algorithm do nothing **(`a` and `b` stay in the same places)**. And if this function returns a value more than zero, `a` and `b` switches **(`b` goes first)**.

Okay, that's understandable. But why my code below works like that?

```js
let arr1 = [9, 3, 6, 7, 1];
console.log(arr1.sort((a, b) => 1)); //1 > 0 -> compare function should switch elements

let arr2 = [9, 3, 6, 7, 1];
console.log(arr2.sort((a, b) => -1)); //-1 < 0 -> compare function shouldn't switch elements
```

Comment: You're sorting `arr1` twice -> `console.log(arr2.sort((a, b) => -1))`

Comment: The problem is, your compare functions are inconsistent. For instance in the first snippet both comparisons `(9,3)` and `(3,9)` return 1. And if that's the case, the result of the sort function is undefined. Same for the second snippet.

Comment: Andreas, since the first result returned an array that was not differently sorted, it didn't affect the result ;)

Comment: @derpirscher the search function provided is not incosistent. it returns the same thing for each pair

Comment: _compare function shouldn't switch elements_ like you say it shouldn't and it doesn't

Comment: @GerardONeill The first `arr1.sort()` did modify the elements: `arr1.sort((a, b) => 1)` -> `[1, 7, 6, 3, 9]`. The second `arr1.sort((a, b) => -1)` will then _not_ modify the order. But that ends in a different order than the one of `arr2`

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze which is an inconsistency, because (9,3) and (3,9) both return the same value. So the final result of the sort solely depends on the order in which the elements are compared, which depends on the used sort algorithm (which may be different in different runtimes)

Comment: @Andreas Did you run the code snippet?  You gonna argue with my lying eyes?

Comment: @derpirscher no that's not inconsistent we can argue that it does not make a lot of sense but it is no inconsistent. You state in your answer _a should be sorted before b_ that's not written in the docs.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze You mean it's not inconsistent if a compare function returns that 9 should be sorted before 3 and 3 should be sorted before 9. Ie, one time 3 is less than 9 and the other time 3 is greater than 9?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze: Thats exactly how it's written in the docs: *"If compareFunction(a, b) returns a value < than 0, sort a before b."*

Comment: @derpirscher that document is only talking about individual elements that the compare function returns a consistent answer for.  compare(1,2) and compare(2,1) both return 1 (or -1 in the second example), which makes the compare function not consistent.  With sorting.  It is consistent with its return value..  So technically the sorting algorithm is free to do whatever it wants.  But since it is doing it using an algorithm, it will sort those values consistently ;), but not in numerical order (in this case).  You might even get an endless loop.

Comment: Oops, I meant @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpreation of the docs is wrong.

You say

> `-1` means elements should stay in the same place.

That's wrong, the docs just state that -1 means *a should be sorted before b*.

Depending on the underlying sorting algorithm, there is no guarantee whatsoever that, when calling the comparefunction with parameters `a` and `b` that `a` is currently before `b` in the array. Ie imagine an array `[1,2,3]`. It *may* be possible that the compare function is called with parameters `(3, 1)` or `(1,3)`. But if you return `-1` in the first case, `1` and `3` will indeed switch positions. And vice versa, if you return `1` in the second case, `1` and `3` will again switch places.

**EDIT**

Different browser implement `sort` differently. For instance if you execute the following snippet in chrome and in firefox you will get different results.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr.sort((a,b) => {
    console.log(`${a}  ${b}`);
  return 1;
})
console.log(arr);
```

For instance in my current chrome (Version 94.0.4606.61 on Windows), `b` will be less than `a` for all calls of the compare function, and thus returning `1` from the compare function would mean, to sort `b` before `a` which is already the case. Thus nothing will change.

Wheras in my firefox (Version 92.0 on Windows) `b` will be greater than `a` for all calls of the compare function. And thus, returning `1` from the compare function would again mean to sort `b` before `a`, which is not currently the case. Thus, the array will be reversed ...

Other runtimes with again a different implementation of `sort` may again lead to other totally unpredictable results ...

Answer (score 0):

If the compare function returns the wrong answer when asked the fundamental question which value is less than the other, why wouldn't you expect the wrong answer from the function that depends on it?

The sort algorithm probably makes the equivalent of two passes before it is done, and ends up returning the values back to its place on the second pass.

I say equivalent - it might be going through once, but on the lower index elements it sorts it one way, and on the higher elements it goes the other way.

For the second case, it considers the top elements sorted, and then the bottom elements it thinks it has to switch.

But sorts all work differently.  A merge sort might depend on how many times it is divisible by 2.  A quick sort might depend on the pivot position. An insertion sort might depend on number of elements being even or odd.

So philosophy aside, the fundamental issue is the following:

```
compare(1, 2) = 1, so switch.
compare(2, 1) = 1, so switch.
```

If you wanted a reason your bad compare function made sort behave the way it did, that is why.

If you actually wanted it to reverse the sort, then you want something like:

```
function compare(int a, int b)
{
  if (a < b) return 1;
  if (a > b) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```